# Multiplication of very Large Diagonal Matrix

Tags: matrices

I have one huge diagonal matrix of dimension $90000$ X $90000$. I want to get the square of it (Say Matrix $A$, I want to have $A$X$A$). In usual way, there should be at least 90000 multiplication which is very slow. Is there any trick to get the square of it in a faster way? Any special algorithm for it? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: In the absence of structure on the diagonal entries, even reading the data takes $O(N)$ time, so I don't see how you expect a substantial improvement.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the right place. I would like to get the attention of moderators, please move if it is not the right place to ask.

Comment: The meaning of "slow" is quite relative and depends on the abacus you run the code on. If you store the diagonal of $A$ in a contiguous array of 90000 floating point numbers, on today's computer you have the result in "no time".

Comment: What Pavel Jiranek said. Unless you need to multiply tens of thousands of such matrices per seconds (literally, 10k/s is easily doable), or you need to do it using medieval hardware, there's no need to worry. 90000 x 90000 *diagonal* matrix is not huge.

Answer (score 4):

Since you need to calculate 90000 entries, which might all be different, it seems like you can't get away with doing less than 90000 multiplications of the original diagonal entries, unless you have some more structure. If you are concerned about the run time on modern CPUs, then you might gain more from avoiding cache misses, rather than avoiding multiplications.